# Как проверить Select на пустоту

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5, javascript-events

Есть объект select:

```
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label asp-for="StreetId" class="control-label"></label>
            <select id="StreetId" asp-for="StreetId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.StreetId"></select>
        </div>
```

Нужно проверить не пуст ли он.

По гуглил и нашел только один метод:

```
var select = document.getElementById('StreetId');
if (!select.empty()) {
...
}
```

Но он выдает ошибку:

> Uncaught TypeError: select.empty is not a function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
if ($('#StreetId').has('option').length === 0) { 
  alert('Пусто!');
} else {
  alert('Не пусто!');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label asp-for="StreetId" class="control-label"></label>
            <select id="StreetId" asp-for="StreetId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.StreetId"></select>
        </div>
```